# Selected Index change event of drop down list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select, selectedindexchanged

I am calling one function which will set the value to html control/asp.net control(Textbox). (i.e. End Date=24 Sep 2013)

However, the function is not changing value of textbox. The function is called on by a Selected Index Change of Drop down list, so the function should change the value of control based on return value of the function.

Thanks & regards,
Vishal Patel

Comment: Could you please provide the code? (HTML + C#) Also have you set either the DropdownList `AutoPostBack` property to be `True` or are you causing an event to refresh the page?

Comment: more code less contact information

Comment: `Please get me solution for this`. Please give us the code for this, to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to know what your doing with out seeing code. but. on your dropdown list make sure you've set the property `AutoPostBack="true"` so that the select index change fires automatically when the drop down list is selected.

Comment: Thanks Eoin, I found solutions . It was not working because i kept all other controls in Update Panel and two textboxes out side of it.